# Google Travel things todo API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

is there any API for getting "Things to do" list for a city?

I have used google places API for searching things todo, with this URL :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=things+to+do+in+Paris,+France&language=en&key=XX

the API result is :

---

Parc Monceau

Arc de Triomphe

Sacré-Cœur

Eiffel Tower

Louvre Museum

---

but as you can see, these results are not sorted by popularity.

for example, the "Parc Monaceau" is not #1 things to do in Paris.

Also when I search "things to do in Paris, France" in google,
The result is this:

---

Eiffel Tower

The Louvre

Arc de Triomphe

Disneyland Paris

Notre-Dame de Paris

---

this is best sorted things to do list , that google will show in search results. but i don't know why i can't get exact this list via google places api.

Also as you can see, the "Disney land" is shown in the google search, but not available in google places API.

please help to fix this.

thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: i have asked how can i sort google search api results with google own search results. is this off-topic question? :)

Comment: Kind of you should consult the documentation first instead of asking someone here to check the Documentation for you.  Most Google apis do not contain a sorting operation.  You will probably have to sort the data locally after it is returned.

Comment: i have checked google places api documentation many times. there is no way to sort , as you said.
i have posted in stackoverflow to give help from others to sort the google results as i wants. 
how can i sort the data by popularity after google returned them?
do you have any solution instead of spamming in the topic?

Comment: As a developer it will be up to you how you sort the data.  No one here is going to code it for you if that is what your looking for.  Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well may be you need to fetch data and sort on your own.

Comment: https://github.com/tuhinpal/thingstodo

Answer (score 8):

I believe the Nearby search might be more suitable for this kind of search. The Nearby search has a `rankby` parameter that you can use to order results by prominense.

Indeed in this case you will need to specify a center of the city position and radius to search.

For example, for Paris it might be

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.856614%2C2.3522219&radius=20000&keyword=things%20to%20do%20in%20Paris&rankby=prominence&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The results that I observe are

- Arc de Triomphe
- Eiffel Tower
- Sacré-Cœur
- Louvre Museum
- Luxembourg Gardens
- Sainte-Chapelle
- Parc Monceau
- Cathédrale Notre-Dame de Paris
- Palais Garnier
- Musée d'Orsay
- .......

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. it has better results than textsearch api.